# What Authorized IPs should I enter to request BlueSnap API credentials?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluesnap

I'm developing an Ionic Cordova hybrid mobile app. I need to integrate BlueSnap's Hosted Payment Page into it. So I started with creating a request to get API credentials, following
[this tutorial](https://support.bluesnap.com/v2.3.1/docs/api-credentials)

But I don't know what IP address should I provide. I need enter the IP address to be used for API calls The backend for app is on Heroku platform. So what IP address should I type to get my API credentials ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a Heroku add-on that provides applications with a fixed set of static IP addresses for outbound requests. There are multiple free and paid options:

- [Fixie](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fixie)
- [QuotaGuard Static](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/quotaguardstatic)
- [Proximo](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo)

Answer (score 0):

you need to enter the IP address of the server that will make the API calls,
If your backend server does not have a static IP address, you can contact Bluesnap support and ask them to disable the IP whitelist check on your bluesnap account. and then it does not meter what API address you set in the allowed IP list